# QAbstractListModel insertRows not working properly

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I have a subclass of QAbstractListModel and attached this model subclass with GridView. When I remove rows from my subclass, the GridView gets updated but when I insert rows in the model the GridView does not gets updated. I have implemented the removeR

I have a very simple subclass of QAbstractListModel and I have attached with it a QML GridView. I have two buttons Add/Remove on the GUI. Pressing Add adds a string to the model and gui updated and pressing remove removes last string from the model and gui updates. My problem is when I add only one row is inserted and when I remove nothing happens on the GUI. Given is the implementation of my model subclass and QML file.

namesmodel.cpp

```
NamesModel::NamesModel(QObject *parent) :
    QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[Qt::UserRole + 1]  = "name";
    setRoleNames(roles);
}
int NamesModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return this->namesList.count();
}
QVariant NamesModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    switch(role) {
    case (Qt::UserRole + 1):
        return this->namesList.at(index.row());
    default:
        return QVariant();
    }
    return QVariant();
}
bool NamesModel::insertRow(int row, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    if ( parent.isValid() )
        return false;
    qDebug() << "Row = " << row;
    beginInsertRows(parent, row, row);
    this->namesList.insert(row, ("Hello World " + QString("%1").arg(row)));
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}
bool NamesModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    int existing_count = this->namesList.count();
    beginInsertRows(parent, row, count);
    for ( int i = existing_count; i < (existing_count + count); i++ )
        this->namesList.insert(i, QString("Multi Hello World = %1").arg(i));
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}
bool NamesModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    int existing_count = this->namesList.count();
    beginRemoveRows(parent, row, count);
    for ( int i = (existing_count + count); i < existing_count; i-- )
        this->namesList.removeAt(i);
    endRemoveRows();
    return true;
}

bool NamesModel::removeRow(int row, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
     beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row);
     this->namesList.removeAt(row);
     endRemoveRows();
}

void NamesModel::addName()
{
    int index = this->namesList.count();
    //insertRow(index, QModelIndex());
    insertRows(index, 5, QModelIndex());
    emit layoutChanged();
    emit dataChanged(this->index(index), this->index(this->namesList.count()));
}
void NamesModel::removeName()
{
    int index = this->namesList.count();
    //removeRow(index, QModelIndex()/*this->index(this->namesList.count())*/);
    removeRows(index, 5, QModelIndex());
    emit layoutChanged();
    emit dataChanged(this->index(index), this->index(index + 5));
}
```

main.qml

```
Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        height: 20
        width: 360/2;
        text: "Add Name"
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                names.addName();
                console.log("Add Name");
            }
        }
    }
    Text {
        height: 20;
        width: 360/2;
        x: 360/2
        text: "Remove Name";
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                names.removeName();
                console.log("Remove Name");
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: gridDelegate

        Text {
            width: 19;      // These are the dimensions of icon image.
            height: 16
            font.pixelSize: 12
            text: name;
        }
    }
    GridView {
        y: 21
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

        focus: true
        model: names;
        delegate: gridDelegate
    }
}
```

I am calling beginInsertRows / endInsertRows and beginRemoveRows / endRemoveRows but it does not seems to work. As suggested on other similar threads I have also called layoutChanged / dataChanged after begin / end InserRows but no effect.

Actually I have almost the same problem with my actual project. I have created this application to test whats wrong with this beginInsertRows etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Farrukh Arshad.

Comment: what is "names" actually QStringList?

Answer (score 6):

The way you are calling [beginInsertRows](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) is incorrect.  In the documentation for the function, you need to provide the first index of the new item (row) and the last "new" index of the items being inserted (row + count - 1).

```
bool NamesModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    int existing_count = this->namesList.count();
    beginInsertRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
    for ( int i = row; i < (row + count - 1); i++ )
        this->namesList.insert(i, QString("Multi Hello World = %1").arg(i));
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}
```

The same goes for [beginRemoveRows](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginRemoveRows).

```
bool NamesModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    int existing_count = this->namesList.count();
    beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
    for ( int i = (row + count - 1); i <= row; i-- )
        this->namesList.removeAt(i);
    endRemoveRows();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith. I tried this but same results. I can add only one row.

Comment: In your addName() function, you don't need to emit the layoutChanged() and dataChanged() signals since you have already notified the views that you have inserted rows.  I am assuming you are using Qt 4.7 or 4.8, right?

Comment: for ( int i = row; i < (row + count - 1); i++ ) is incorrect. When count == 1, nothing will be added.